# How to choose a circle for default stream in Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus

How can I choose a specific circle for the default stream in Google+ ? Many extensions don't work, and are not comfortable if using another PC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Streams of Circles are just web pages, you don't need an extension to do this.

I hope that there will be a feature in Google+ to do this.

But what I do is that I copy the link of the circle, it will be something like this:`https://plus.google.com/stream/circles/p6a5598f68a00498712` , and I add it to Bookmarks.

Comment: thx, applied to j.mp makes it quite usable