# How do I set a community to be the landing page when I go to plus.google.com?

Tags: google-plus

plus.google.com takes me to a feed that I am not interested in. I am only interested in seeing a single specific community's page. Is there a way to set this by default? If not that, can I set (https://plus.google.com/communities) to be the default tab that is opened?

Edit - communities did not exist in 2011, is that still the only answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to choose a circle for default stream in Google Plus?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18244/how-to-choose-a-circle-for-default-stream-in-google-plus)

Comment: @Eight: I don't think it's a duplicate. That's about Circles, this is about Communities.

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise: At this time there is only one answer and it doesn't apply to this question.

Comment: Communities work the same as Circles, but how they're controlled is different

Answer (score 1):

At this time there isn't a preference to set the tab to be displayed when the user go to http://plus.google.com. Instead of typing the URL or the default link in the Google apps launcher use a bookmark to go to the page that you want.

Related help article:  [Get started with your home stream](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/6320389?hl=en)